# Filtering using a str array

Tags: python, string

I am trying to filter an ASCII list (which contains ASCII and other characters) by using an array that I have created. I am trying to remove any integer string within the list.

```py
import pandas as pd
with open('ASCII.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().replace('\t', ',')
    print(data, file=open('my_file.csv', 'w'))
df = list(data)
test = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

for x in df:
    try:
        df = int(df)
        for i in range(0,9):
            while any(test) in df:
                df.remove('i') 
        print(df)
    except:
        continue

print(df)
```

This is what I currently have however, it does not work and outputs:

```py
['3', '3', ',', '0', '4', '1', ',', '2', '1', ',', '!', ',', '\n', '3', '4', ',', '0', '4', ...]
```

Comment: What are the contents of `data`? Are there any errors? If so, please [edit] your post and add their [*full text*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146). Why are you importing `pandas` and not using it? To figure out what the error(s) is/are, remove the `try`/`except` and just let the code run. `except: continue` is just masking any errors and preventing them from being seen. You can't call `int()` on a list, so that's one error. `while any(test) in df` isn't doing what you think it's doing. `for i in range(0,9): ... df.remove("i")` isn't going to do what you want it to.

Comment: Forgot one: up at the top, you're reading the contents of your text file into a string, replacing tabs with commas along the way. Calling `list()` on a string isn't doing what you probably think it's doing - try it at an interactive prompt.

Comment: Here are some hints: Test each line in an interactive session so it does what you want it to *before* putting it into a larger block of code. Constantly look at the values of your variables so they are what you think they are. Read the documentation for all of the functions you're using, to make sure they do what you want them to do. Actively look for errors, don't hide them.

Comment: Just to note: your entire loop can be replaced with a one-liner: `df = [c for c in data if c not in string.digits]`

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` condition for numbers is broken.
`any` checks if at least one element in the passed iterable is truthy, i.e. not an empty string in your case.

```py
test = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
while any(test) in df:  # Condition always evaluates to False
    df.remove('i')  # Only removes the character 'i' from df
```

So your condition `any(test)` evaluates to `True`. And now you are checking if `True` is in `df` which it isn't, so the condition evaluates to `False`.
The next error is, that you try to remove the letter `'i'` from your list with the `remove` call. This can be fixed by casting the integer to a string

```py
for i in range(9):
    # Cast integer to str
    while str(i) in df:
        # Remove str i from df
        df.remove(str(i))
```

Using a `str` list instead of the `range` function, you can directly iterate over the elements of the `test` list:

```py
df = list(data)
test = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

for num in test:
    # Loop as long as num appears in df
    while num in df:
        df.remove(num)  # removes all elements with value of num
```

By doing so you have to run a second loop to remove all appearances of the current `num` in `df`, as `remove` only removes the first occurrence of that value.

Alternatively you can also check each element of `df` if it is a digit by using the `str` method `isdigit`. But as you modify the list in-place you need to iterate over a copy. Otherwise you'll encounter side-effects as you reduce the size of `df`:

```py
# Use slice to create a copy of df
for el in df[:]:
    if el.isdigit():
        df.remove(el)
```

As you iterate over each element in `df` you don't need an inner loop to remove each occurrence of value `el`.

Comment: Thank you I tried this, and it worked just as I wanted. I'm new to coding and did not know about the isdigit function. cheers buddy